# Why does firefox ignore media.peerconnection.enabled option?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-developer-tools

I write automate bot in selenium and think a little about anonymity so I suggest to disable WebRTC in firefox driver by this command options.set_preference("media.peerconnection.enabled", False) but when I start code and in "about:config" looks to check it - it is enabled(True but should be False).
Minimum code for test(Python):

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("media.peerconnection.enabled", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://iphey.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use a FirefoxProfile() so:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 

fp.set_preference("media.peerconnection.enabled", False)
fp.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp, executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://iphey.com")
```